# Wireguard service seems to start before network is really online

Tags: networking, server, raspberrypi, wireguard

I am going a little crazy trying to make Wireguard work on Ubuntu Server 23.10 running on a Raspberry-Pi5.

Overall, Wireguard configuration works. I can bring `wg0` up and down. But if I reboot the pi, the Wireguard systemd service will fail:

```
-- Boot --
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd[1]: Starting wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip -4 address add X.X.X.X/32 dev wg0
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[663]: RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
Feb 10 17:25:26 host wg-quick[600]: [#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[600]: [#] resolvectl dns wg0 9.9.9.9; resolvectl domain wg0 \~.; resolvectl default-route eth0 false
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[600]: [#] iptables -I OUTPUT ! -o wg0 -m mark ! --mark $(wg show wg0 fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -o wg0 -m mark ! --mark $(wg show wg0 >
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[600]: [#] iptables -I OUTPUT -m iprange --dst-range 10.10.10.2-10.10.10.14 -j ACCEPT
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip route add 10.10.10.0/28 via 172.20.30.1 dev eth0
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[727]: Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[600]: [#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip -4 rule delete table 51820
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip -4 rule delete table main suppress_prefixlength 0
Feb 10 17:25:27 host wg-quick[600]: [#] ip link delete dev wg0
Feb 10 17:25:27 host systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Feb 10 17:25:27 host systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 10 17:25:27 host systemd[1]: Failed to start wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

This would leave an unclean iptables state.
However, if I cleanup iptables `sudo iptables -F` and try to bring `wg0` up manually, this will work with no issues.

Now, I am not doing anything very uncommon. Essentially, I follow these steps:

- Install Ubuntu Server 23.10 using Raspberry Pi Imager
- Disable NetworkInterfaceNames (to stick with static names - eth0, etc)
- `apt update` and `apt upgrade`
- Install Wireguard
- Configure Wireguarg and bring up `wg0`
- Enable Wireguard service

Notice, that this same configuration/approach is working on Ubuntu Server 23.04 running on a Raspberry-PI3, where the Wireguard service will start and finish successfully with no issue.

At this point everything works as expected. I can bring down and up `wg0` with no issues.
But if I restart the PI, the wireguard-service will fail.
My current guess is that for some reason the Wireguard Service starts before the network is really online. This is based on the following logs, where you can see that Wireguard started sooner that systemd-networkd reported back that it received the config from DHCP:

```
-- Boot --
Feb 10 17:25:25 host systemd[1]: Starting systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration...
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd-networkd[451]: lo: Link UP
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd-networkd[451]: lo: Gained carrier
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd-networkd[451]: Enumeration completed
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd[1]: Started systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration.
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd-networkd[451]: eth0: found matching network '/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network', based on potentially unpredictable interface name.
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd-networkd[451]: eth0: Configuring with /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network.
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd-networkd[451]: eth0: Link UP
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd-networkd[451]: wg0: Link UP
Feb 10 17:25:26 host systemd-networkd[451]: wg0: Gained carrier
Feb 10 17:25:27 host systemd-networkd[451]: wg0: Link DOWN
Feb 10 17:25:27 host systemd-networkd[451]: wg0: Lost carrier
Feb 10 17:25:30 host systemd-networkd[451]: eth0: Gained carrier
Feb 10 17:25:30 host systemd-networkd[451]: eth0: found matching network '/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network', based on potentially unpredictable interface name.
Feb 10 17:25:30 host systemd-networkd[451]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 172.20.30.14/28, gateway 172.20.30.1 acquired from 172.20.30.1
Feb 10 17:25:31 host systemd-networkd[451]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
```

However, `wg-quick@.service` is basically the default file, where one can see that the service is dependent on network-online.target, which should make wireguard start only when network is really online:

```
[Unit]
Description=WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for %I
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target nss-lookup.target

PartOf=wg-quick.target
Documentation=man:wg-quick(8)
Documentation=man:wg(8)
Documentation=https://www.wireguard.com/
Documentation=https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
Documentation=https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
Documentation=https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/wg-quick down %i
ExecReload=/bin/bash -c 'exec /usr/bin/wg syncconf %i <(exec /usr/bin/wg-quick strip %i)'
Environment=WG_ENDPOINT_RESOLUTION_RETRIES=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So, I do not understand why this may be happening and how it could be mitigated. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

---

Adding network-online status:

```
network-online.target - Network is Online
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/network-online.target; static)
     Active: active since Sat 2024-02-10 18:42:29; 1h 24min ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
             https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE

Feb 10 18:42:29 host systemd[1]: Reached target network-online.target - Network is Online
```

Comment: Please [edit] with `systemctl status network-online.target`

Comment: @DanielT added the output. However, I do not understand how this might help in this case, as I mentioned that the problem is during boot process.

Comment: So that target is enabled. Another thing you can try is setting `ExecStartPre` to be a script file that runs a loop waiting for the network to be up

Answer (score 2):

Mentioned issue seems to be related to how systemd works and when a network is considered to be up. See: https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE/

> **What does “up” actually mean?**
>
> The services that are ordered before network-online.target define its meaning. Usually means that all configured network devices are up and have an IP address assigned, but details may vary. In particular, configuration may affect which interfaces are taken into account.

Systemd documentation overall mentions different approaches on how to deal with such situations.

But I personally, have opted by introducing a "ExecStartPre" command in Wireguard service as mentioned by @Daniel T in the comments.

```
...
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=sh -c 'until ping -c 1 example.com; do sleep 1; done'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/wg-quick down %i
ExecReload=/bin/bash -c 'exec /usr/bin/wg syncconf %i <(exec /usr/bin/wg-quick strip %i)'
Environment=WG_ENDPOINT_RESOLUTION_RETRIES=infinity
...
```

This solution may not be the most elegant one, but it's major benefit is that I do not need to mess with network-online or any other services.

However, if someone needs a more robust solution which would work for many dependent services, I advice to look at systemd documentation:

> It is also possible to plug in additional checks for network state. For example, to delay network-online.target until some a specific host is reachable (the name can be resolved over DNS and the appropriate route has been established), the following simple service could be used:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
After=nss-lookup.target
Before=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=sh -c 'until ping -c 1 example.com; do sleep 1; done'

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```